# Duplication of field error when using Parsley.js

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I am trying to output a list of error messages to the console when a form input is not validated. I am using parsley.js.

Here is the javascript I am using. This works, but I get a duplication of every error and I am unsure what is causing this?

```
(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demo-form").parsley();
    // listen for error messages
    $.listen('parsley:field:error', function(fieldInstance){
        // get error messages
        ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(fieldInstance);
        // Log error messages to console using input id to identify
        console.log(fieldInstance.$element.attr('id'));
    });
});
```

** Update **

As requested I have given a working example of this. I have a script that outputs the console.log into a div at the top of the screen, for some reason I can't get this to work on JSFiddle. However you can see the duplicated output in the console regardless.

http://jsfiddle.net/eah6sd99/4/

Comment: You should post the code of your form so we can see the validations for each field.

Comment: Sure, I have created a JS fiddle with part of the form I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the fields duplicated because you're validating the form twice. The relevant portion of code is:

```
$.listen('parsley:field:validate', function () {
  validateFront();
});

$('#demo-form .btn').on('click', function () {
  $('#demo-form').parsley().validate();
  validateFront();
});

$('.next').on('click', function () {
    var current = $(this).data('currentBlock'),
      next = $(this).data('nextBlock');

    if (next > current)
      if (false === $('#demo-form').parsley().validate('block' + current))
        return;
```

When you click on the "Next" button, you trigger `parsley().validate('block' + current)` within your condition, which validates the group.

In adition, you have `$('#demo-form').parsley().validate();` whenever you click a `.btn` from `#demo-form` which means you're validating the same portion of the form twice.

To solve this issue, you simply need to remove the `$('#demo-form .btn').on('click', function () {` code. Check [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/vv4ccjp6/1/) for a working example (I've merged all your `document.ready` code to keep it more readable).

---

If you want to display the messages above the form, you can do so with the following code:

```
$.listen('parsley:field:error', function(fieldInstance){
    var messages = ParsleyUI.getErrorsMessages(fieldInstance);
    $('.bs-callout-warning').append('<b>' +
        fieldInstance.$element.parent().find('label').text() + 
        '</b><br />' + 
        messages + '<br />');
});
```

Check [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/vv4ccjp6/2/).